# MySQL optimizing the query by applying date() function on left side

Tags: mysql

Can anyone please suggest how to optimize the below query with out applying the date function on column datecol1 in where condition. We already has the index on datecol1 but it is not being considering because of the `date()` function on left side.

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATE(datecol2)
FROM table1
WHERE DATE(datecol1) BETWEEN DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 HOUR)) AND
                             DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR));
```

Thanks for the help!

Update:
Table has following rows:

```
 datecol2               datecol1    
'2016-06-17 01:10:07', '2016-07-02 01:41:44'    
'2016-06-20 17:18:49', '2016-07-02 01:01:16'     
'2016-06-21 18:22:16', '2016-07-02 00:57:30'    
'2016-06-23 16:09:21', '2016-07-02 00:01:51'     
'2016-06-23 16:13:24', '2016-07-02 00:01:51'     
'2016-06-23 16:14:07', '2016-07-01 23:01:51'     
'2016-06-24 16:14:07', '2016-07-01 07:01:51'    
'2016-06-25 16:14:07', '2016-07-01 08:11:51'
```

So, we need all the last 3 rows to be picked as it matches with date(colname) i.e 2016-07-01 along with 2016-07-02
The query looks like

```
 SELECT DISTINCT DATE(datecol2) FROM table1
 WHERE DATE(datecol1) BETWEEN DATE('2016-07-01 23:00:00') AND  DATE('2016-07-02 05:00:00');
```

Comment: why you want that date function on datecol1 ? what is your logic

Comment: You could consider storing your dates as seconds since epoch.

Comment: show how does `datecol1` value look?

Comment: Yes, what is the type of `datecol1`?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest datecol1 looks like "2016-07-02 00:32:23" (it also includes the time but I need search on with yyyy-mm-dd with excluding time)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen datetime type

Comment: but your date sub function will return it with time ?? mysql> select date_sub(now(), interval 7 hour);
+----------------------------------+
| date_sub(now(), interval 7 hour) |
| 2016-07-02 05:39:33              |

Comment: @MaheshMadushanka it was a typo. Updated the query in the original question posted

Comment: I'd like to see a concrete example of what you're actually to do

Comment: @Strawberry Updated the post with example

Comment: Yeah - it still doesn't make sense

Comment: I think you mean midnight (zero-hour) on datecol1. E.g.: '2016-07-01 00:00:00'

Comment: @Strawberry .. Suppose a record is edited at "2016-07-01 07:01:51", then I need to retrieve all records for the given date .. hope this makes it clear..I am now doing this by using date(colname) .. but this is preventing the index from being used. Therefore, I am looking for an alternative way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If `datecol1` has `DATETIME` type - there's no need to apply `DATE` function in such case. All the crucial argumnents in `WHERE` clause are `DATETIME` values because `DATE_SUB` returns `DATETIME` value also:

```
SELECT distinct DATE(datecol2) 
FROM table1
WHERE datecol1 
      BETWEEN date_sub(now(), interval 7 hour) 
      AND date_sub(now(), interval 1 hour);
```

For example, the following query will return `1`:

```
select 1 from CatalogAreas
where '2016-07-02 08:00:00' between date_sub(now(), interval 7 hour)  and date_sub(now(), interval 1 hour)
limit 1;
```

Comment: Thanks Roman.But this may not work as I need all the records which are reported on 2016-07-01.

Comment: I need in this way : select 1 from CatalogAreas
where '2016-07-02' between date_sub(now(), interval 7 hour)  and date_sub(now(), interval 1 hour)
limit 1;

Comment: you should know, that `date_sub` returns `datetime` value if the first argument is a DATETIME (or TIMESTAMP) value. So, this `where '2016-07-02' between date_sub(now(), interval 7 hour) and date_sub(now(), interval 1 hour) ` doesn't make much sense

Comment: We have modified original post with applying the date functions. So it should be  select 1 from CatalogAreas where '2016-07-02' between date(date_sub(now(), interval 7 hour)) and date(date_sub(now(), interval 1 hour)) limit 1; Sorry for the typo.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add